# MNIST training example in AIFH Vol 3

Tags: c#, neural-network, encog

I have a question regarding the structure of this neural network:

```
var network = new BasicNetwork();
network.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(null, true, inputCount));
network.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationReLU(), true, 100));
network.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationReLU(), true, 50));
network.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationReLU(), true, 25));
network.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationSoftMax(), false, outputCount));
network.FinalizeStructure();
network.Reset();
```

According to the text in the book, network with one hidden layer is suffice for most of the problem and network with two hidden layers are also known as deep neural networks, whereas the network with 3 hidden layers are rare, now what makes the developer decide to use 3 hidden layers and how the neuron count is decided for each layer?

Answer (score 0):

The answers to "[How to choose the number of hidden layers and nodes in a feedforward neural network?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181/how-to-choose-the-number-of-hidden-layers-and-nodes-in-a-feedforward-neural-netw/1097#1097)" indicate that three or more hidden layer networks are often impossible to train, and also gives a reference to one of Jeff Heaton's (creator of ENCOG) books in which he states that "There is currently no theoretical reason to use neural networks with any more than two hidden layers".

In other words, the developer shouldn't decide to use 3 hidden layers.

The above referenced [Stack Exchange article on ENCOG](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181/how-to-choose-the-number-of-hidden-layers-and-nodes-in-a-feedforward-neural-netw/1097#1097) also gives some interesting formulas for calculating the number neurons in each layer.